# DOM addressing with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I don't know what it is called but can anyone direct me to a tutorial or something which will enlighten me on how to address HTML DOM elements in jquery??

For Example, I want to know the difference between `$('#someid div')` or `$('#someid > div')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery uses CSS selectors for addressing HTML elements. Read [the **jQuery documentation on its selectors** (api.jquery.com/category/selectors)](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to know the details.

The difference between the selectors you mentioned is following:

- `#someid div` gets you all `div` elements located inside element with ID=`someid`,
- `#someid > div` gets you all `div` elements located inside element with ID=`someid`, but not enclosed in different elements located in element with ID=`someid` - that means that the `div` elements have to be "childs", not just "descendants" of the element with specified ID,

So, the **second selector is more specific** and **the first one is broader**.

More on "child selector" is in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the best reference from the jQuery documentation itself:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Selectors are based on CSS selectors so you should get an idea of how they work before you start using them.

$('#someid div') will select the first div within someid that is a direct child, grandchild, etc...

or $('#someid > div') will select only the first child div within the #someid container.